# android - How to create folder on sdcard with app icon with left down corner?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-sdcard

I want to create a folder programatically for my app same as this screen shot.

I tried on google but not getting proper out put.

check attach screen shot this screen shot is for showing a reference of Folder with icon.

Image captures from Es explorer file manager.

[image]

Comment: for that you have to create a folder drawable with app icon under it.

Comment: @Kartheek Can you please provide some code if you have.

Comment: set Button ingridLayout and in Button set DrawableTop property as icon then you can set this type of View

Comment: This is just an GridView. And two imageviews. One is for the folder and another one is for the icon. If icon is not needed just change the visibility to gone

Comment: @HirenVaghela this screen shot captured by SDcard this is not my app. I want to create folder programatically like whats app.

Comment: which file browser you use i this this browser provide this fecilities.

Comment: @HirenVaghela  Not Browser I want to make folder in data/data path with icon of my app. Screen shot is for reference.

Comment: @All thank you it's not possible from our side.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create a folder programatically for my app same as this screen shot.

To create a directory (a.k.a., folder), call `mkdirs()` on a `File` object, using standard Java file I/O.

> check attach screen shot this screen shot is for showing a reference of Folder with icon.

You will have to contact the developers of that app and ask them what they are using to identify the icon to apply to a particular directory. Directories in Android (and most other operating systems) do not have icons themselves.